# Can functors always replace callbacks

Tags: c++, callback, functor

In C++ can  functors always replace callbacks? Or there are cases when "regular" callbacks are needed?
I.e. each function that takes a function pointer , take instead a functor ,having the same arguments and return value as the function pointer?

Comment: Depends on your definition of callback.  If you need to work with a C API callback (so a function pointer) then the answer is no.

Comment: A functor is not compatible with a C-style function pointer.  But a non-capturing lambda is compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Traditional C function pointers can not be substituted using just any functor.
So structs with `operator()` overloads or lambdas with capture variables will not work. See the following code:

```cpp
#include <functional>

// this function takes a void() function pointer
void run_callback(void(*callback)()) {
    callback();
}

// this function takes a std::function
void run_function(std::function<void()> fun) {
    fun();
}

struct Callable {
    void operator()();
};

int main() {
    int x;
    run_callback([](){});     // OK
    run_callback([x](){});    // ERROR, we are not allowed to capture x
    run_callback(Callable{}); // ERROR, can't convert Callable to function pointer

    run_function([](){});     // OK
    run_function([x](){});    // ALSO OK
    run_function(Callable{}); // ALSO OK
}
```

If you want a solution that just works for anything from function pointers to lambdas/functors, then use `std::function`.

C function pointers are necessary when calling C APIs from C++.

C function pointers are also better in performance critical applications.
`std::function` can take anything because internally, it wraps function pointers and functors in a polymorphic wrapper class. This requires a virtual function call, meaning that `std::function` needs to dereference a pointer before it knows what to call. Also `std::function` can be empty. As a result, it needs to test each call whether it is empty and throws `std::bad_function_call` if so.